# LaTeX - Split table over two pager (document with 2 text columns)

Tags: tables, split, page

what do I have to change in this code to split the table over two pages?
I have already tried "longtable", but it seems like it doesn't work with 2 text columns on the page. "tabularx" also doesn't seem to work here, or I did something wrong.

```
\documentclass[9pt,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[format=plain, indention=1cm]{caption}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
%.......................................Table..................................
\begin{table*}[!htb]
\captionsetup{size=footnotesize}
\captionsetup{justification=centering}
\caption{Heading} \label{tab:Table}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
 
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}p{3.3cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}p{4cm}}
\hline
\toprule

\multirow{2}{*}{\shortstack[l]{Col1}} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Col2} \\ \cline{2-4} \\
&SubCol&SubCol&SubCol\\

  \hline
\midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
    \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
    \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  \midrule
  Entr1 &  &     \\
  
\bottomrule
\hline
\end{tabular*}
\end{table*}
%..................................EndeTable..................................
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Ok, done. Should be a working example now.